# If a vector subspace is open, then it's the whole space

Tags: vector-spaces

If $V'$ is a subspace of $V$ and it is open then $V=V'$.

I've seen a similar question about this, but they talk about "non-empty interiors", is non-empty intetior similar to talkin about open sets?
also, why people suggest taking a ball arround 0 ?

Comment: in a normed vector space $V,\|.\|$, a subset $U$ is open means that for any $u \in U$, there exists  $\epsilon$ such that the $\epsilon$ ball around $u$ is in $U$, i.e. if $\|v-u\| < \epsilon$ then $v \in U$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a **normed** vector space, this is true. If $x$ is in the interior of $V'$, there is $r>0$ such that the closed ball $\overline{B}(x,r)\subseteq V'$. Then for any $y \neq 0$ in $V$ we have $$\Vert (x+ry/\Vert y\Vert )-x\Vert =r,$$ so $x+ry/\Vert y\Vert \in V'$. Since $V'$ is a subspace and $x \in V'$, we have $y \in V'$.

Comment: But why did yoiu take the closed ball?

Comment: So I wouldn't have terms with $r/2$.

Comment: Sorry heh, but how did you conclude $x+\frac{ry}{||y||}\in V'$

Comment: Because it is in the closed ball that is contained in $V'$

Comment: one last question, when did you consider it's an open subspace?, is it when you took the ball arround an interior point?

Comment: This is a stronger result than assuming openness. An open set is one in which all its points are interior. This shows all you need is one interior point. So in particular, if $V'$ is open, since $0 \in V'$, we can use my argument for $x=0$, so conclude $V'=V$.

Comment: Does everything work for you?

Comment: I'm sorry, :/ no, I'd appreciate a sentence which says: "Since V' is open ..... ". Thank you for patience !

Comment: I SEE IT! "Since V' is open, we can take any x to be an interior point and do the Ball arround it !!!!!"

Comment: Exactly. ${}{} $